# Can column values be accessed like an array in SQL server

Tags: sql, arrays, select

Can column values be accessed like an array in SQL server. for instance  `Select x[1] from tableA` gives me the value for that field.   I'm attempting to do this @OldValue =  (SELECT @fieldname FROM #del).  But this just returns the actual field name not the field value

Comment: Not like that, they can't. What are you trying to do? What is X, a column in tableA? What does it contain?

Comment: If you use C# and execute a SQL query, you can reference the results by ordinal position, but not in SQL itself.

Comment: I'm trying to get a value from the deleted table without specifying the column name in the query. So it can be dynamic.  @OldValue =  (SELECT d.NAME FROM #del).

Comment: Why would you want to select some column without knowing which? That makes no sense. If it is some GUI where some user selects a column name from a list, then the column is known in that very moment and you can build your query (i.e. a string) and send it to the DBMS.

Comment: Look up "dynamic SQL" and sp_executesql, if you want to build the SQL in an SQL Server stored procedure.

Comment: Is your purpose to make a universal trigger for auditing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

No. Data in tables is not ordered, so there is no first, second, etc. record. You access a record by some criteria, e.g. a user by a user ID or login name, an employee by an employee number, etc. Or you use technical IDs to access records.

If you want the fifth record according to some order you can usually use some limit clause. E.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
ORDER BY userid
OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

fetches the 5th record ordered by user ID.

As to columns: They are accessed by their names. E.g.:

```
SELECT name
FROM user
ORDER BY userid
OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

As you see it would make no sense to have some Excel-like access, because you need an order by clause and accessing columns via name rather than by some letter or number is even more readable and less prone to errors.